# Not getting the expected values upon form submission

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form where I ask the user to enter some values. Then, using PHP, I'm trying to process the values the user entered.

The issue I'm facing is that, after the user submitted the form, all my values are set to `1` instead of the value the user entered.

Here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="checkOutResult.php">
    <p> Transaction #:
        <input type="text" name="transactionNum" placeholder="Input #">
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Student ID</td>
            <td>Employee ID</td>
            <td>Professor ID</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="studentID" placeholder="7 Digit Student ID">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="empID" placeholder="7 Digit Employee ID">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="profID" placeholder="7 Digit Professor ID">
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Product ID</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="productID" placeholder="Scan Barcode">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i4nrjjak/n179/fn10/fs24/fcb40431/ftb/bas2/bat1/bacfff/pa8/tt0/tw1/td2/th2/tb4" frameborder="0" width="334" height="74"></iframe>

                <td>CheckOut Date</td>
                <td>CheckOut Time</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="checkoutDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="checkoutTime" placeholder="HH:MM:SS">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>

    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Due Date</td>
                <td>Due Time</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="dueDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="dueTime" placeholder="HH:MM:SS">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This is the PHP code that is executed upon form submission.

```
<?php

include ("thesis.php");

$transactionNum = isset($_POST['transactionNum']);
$studentID = isset($_POST['studentID']);
$empID = isset($_POST['empID']);
$profID = isset($_POST['profID']);
$productID = isset($_POST['productID']);
$checkoutDate = isset($_POST['checkoutDate']);
$checkoutTime = isset($_POST['checkoutTime']);
$dueDate = isset($_POST['dueDate']);
$dueTime = isset($_POST['dueTime']);

$query = "INSERT INTO Transactions(transactionNum, studentID, empID, profID, productID, checkoutDate, checkoutTime, dueDate, dueTime)
    VALUES ('$transactionNum', '$studentID', '$empID', '$profID', '$productID', '$checkoutDate', '$checkoutTime', '$dueDate', '$dueTime')";

if($link->query($query) === TRUE){
    echo "New Record Created Successfully. ";
    echo"<br>";
} 

else{
    echo" Error: " .$query ."<br>" .$link->error;
}

echo"<br>";
echo "Transacton #: ".$transactionNum;
echo"<br>";
echo "Student ID: ".$profID;
echo"<br>";
echo "Employee ID: ".$empID;
echo"<br>";
echo "Professor ID: ".$profID;
echo"<br>";
echo "Product ID: ".$productID;
echo"<br>";
echo "Out Date: ".$checkoutDate;
echo"<br>";
echo "Out Time: ".$checkoutTime;
echo"<br>";
echo "Due Date: ".$dueDate;
echo"<br>";
echo "Due Time: ".$dueTime;
echo"<br>";
?>
```

Why do I keep getting `1`s instead of the values I submit with the form?

Answer (score 0):

The following command retuns `true` (`1` as a string) if the field `empID` isset in your `$_POST` data.

```
$empID =isset($_POST['empID']);
```

it should be

```
$empID = isset($_POST['empID']) ? $_POST['empID'] : "";
```

and so on.

Which means: catch the `empID` of `$_POST` if there is one, else catch an empty string. It is a short version of the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['empID'])) {
    $empID = $_POST['empID'];
} else {
    $empID = "";
}
```

Comment: doesn't help, now its blank

Comment: @JhonnyUrgiles if it is blank, it doesn't have a value / Field `empID` is empty. However, this is the correct way to fetch `$_POST` variables. Maybe you should do a `print_r($_POST)` first, to see if you got the expected values.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting boolean for isset here
`$empID = isset($_POST['empID']);`
Which is why it is giving you a value of `1` as that is the value for `true` in this case.

Resolve with `if isset($_POST['empID']) {$empID = $_POST['empID'];}`